# DirectX 11 Translation/Rotation Issue

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, matrix-multiplication

I can translate my 2d image to 0, 0 using the below code.

```
D3DXMATRIX worldMatrix, viewMatrix, orthoMatrix, rotation, movement;

// Get the world, view, and ortho matrices from the camera.
m_camera.GetViewMatrix(viewMatrix);
m_camera.GetWorldMatrix(worldMatrix);
m_camera.GetOrthoMatrix(orthoMatrix);

// Move the texture to the new position
D3DXMatrixTranslation(&movement, ((m_VerticeProperties->screenWidth / 2) * -1) + m_posX, 
    (m_VerticeProperties->screenHeight / 2) - m_posY, 0.0f);

worldMatrix = movement;

//float m_rotationZ = -90 * 0.0174532925f;
//D3DXMatrixRotationYawPitchRoll(&rotation, 0, 0, m_rotationZ);
//worldMatrix = rotation;

// Give the bitmap class what it needs to make source rect
m_bitmap->SetVerticeProperties(m_VerticeProperties->screenWidth, m_VerticeProperties->screenHeight, 
    m_VerticeProperties->frameWidth, m_VerticeProperties->frameHeight, m_VerticeProperties->U, m_VerticeProperties->V);

//Render the model (the vertices)
m_bitmap->Render(m_d3dManager.GetDeviceContext(), flipped);

//Render the shader
m_shader->Render(m_d3dManager.GetDeviceContext(), m_bitmap->GetIndexCount(), worldMatrix, viewMatrix, 
    orthoMatrix, m_bitmap->GetTexture(), m_textureTranslationU, m_VerticeProperties->translationPercentageV);
```

The result:

[image]

I can also rotate the image with this code:

```
D3DXMATRIX worldMatrix, viewMatrix, orthoMatrix, rotation, movement;

// Get the world, view, and ortho matrices from the camera.
m_camera.GetViewMatrix(viewMatrix);
m_camera.GetWorldMatrix(worldMatrix);
m_camera.GetOrthoMatrix(orthoMatrix);

//// Move the texture to the new position
//D3DXMatrixTranslation(&movement, ((m_VerticeProperties->screenWidth / 2) * -1) + m_posX, 
//  (m_VerticeProperties->screenHeight / 2) - m_posY, 0.0f);

//worldMatrix = movement;

float m_rotationZ = 90 * 0.0174532925f;
D3DXMatrixRotationYawPitchRoll(&rotation, 0, 0, m_rotationZ);
worldMatrix = rotation;

// Give the bitmap class what it needs to make source rect
m_bitmap->SetVerticeProperties(m_VerticeProperties->screenWidth, m_VerticeProperties->screenHeight, 
    m_VerticeProperties->frameWidth, m_VerticeProperties->frameHeight, m_VerticeProperties->U, m_VerticeProperties->V);

//Render the model (the vertices)
m_bitmap->Render(m_d3dManager.GetDeviceContext(), flipped);

//Render the shader
m_shader->Render(m_d3dManager.GetDeviceContext(), m_bitmap->GetIndexCount(), worldMatrix, viewMatrix, 
    orthoMatrix, m_bitmap->GetTexture(), m_textureTranslationU, m_VerticeProperties->translationPercentageV);
```

The result:

[image]

I thought multiplying the translation and rotation matrices and setting them = to the world matrix would allow me to see both effects at once.

```
D3DXMatrixTranslation(&movement, ((m_VerticeProperties->screenWidth / 2) * -1) + m_posX, 
    (m_VerticeProperties->screenHeight / 2) - m_posY, 0.0f);

float m_rotationZ = 90 * 0.0174532925f;
D3DXMatrixRotationYawPitchRoll(&rotation, 0, 0, m_rotationZ);
worldMatrix = rotation * movement;
```

It doesn't. The image no longer appears on the screen.

Can anyone tell me what im doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Do me a favor and try translating by a much smaller amount, maybe a fifth of the screen height and width, and see if the square appears then. I'm very rusty but I think when you rotate and translate, you're moving the axes with the object when you rotate. Since your screen is probably wider than higher, that would move it out of view. You'd be moving half the screen width, but down, in an absolute sense.

Comment: BTW you should look at moving to [DirectXMath](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/03/26/introducing-directxmath/) or the [SimpleMath](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SimpleMath) wrapper for it. D3DXMath is ancient.

Comment: Rotation is always around the center of your coordinate system. So the correct way of rotation a translated objekt is:

Translate Objekt to center -> Rotate -> translate Objekt to end position

Comment: so would that be world matrix = Translate Objekt to center matrix * Rotate matrix * translate Objekt to end position matrix  ?

Answer (score 0):

just do world * -translate * rotation * translate it will make you rotate local
here my code for example

```
void Ojbect::RotZ(float angle, Vec3 origin)
{
    Mat4 w, rz, t;
    rz.RotZ(angle);
    t.Translation(-origin.x, -origin.y, 0);
    w = t * rz * -1 * t;
    Vec4 newPos;
    for (int i = 0; i < countV; i++)
    {
        Vec3 pos(vertex[i].x, vertex[i].y, 1);
        newPos.Transform(pos, w);
        vertex[i].x = newPos.x;
        vertex[i].y = newPos.y;
    }
    UpdateVertex(countV);
}
```